# C# install Cursor installer (.inf) file

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, cursor, inf

I have a cursor installer file (installer.inf). Is it possible to install the cursor using C#?

I already tried the following code but it doesn't work and nothing happens when getting executed:

```cs
[DllImport("Setupapi.dll", EntryPoint = "InstallHinfSection", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void InstallHinfSection([In] IntPtr hwnd, [In] IntPtr ModuleHandle, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string CmdLineBuffer, int nCmdShow);

public static void InstallCursor(string installerFilePath)
{
    InstallHinfSection(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, installerFilePath, 0);
}
```

---

By cursor installer, I mean the following file that is present when installing a new cursor on Windows:

[image: Cursor-Installer-Files]

Here, the installer.inf file looks like this:

```
[Version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"

[DefaultInstall]
CopyFiles = Scheme.Cur, Scheme.Txt
AddReg    = Scheme.Reg

[DestinationDirs]
Scheme.Cur = 10,"%CUR_DIR%"
Scheme.Txt = 10,"%CUR_DIR%"

[Scheme.Reg]
HKCU,"Control Panel\Cursors\Schemes","%SCHEME_NAME%",,"%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%pointer%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%help%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%work%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%busy%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%Cross%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%Text%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%Hand%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%Unavailiable%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%Vert%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%Horz%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%Dgn1%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%Dgn2%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%move%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%alternate%,%10%\%CUR_DIR%\%link%"

[Scheme.Cur]
"Normal Select.cur"
"Help Select.ani"
"Work in Background.ani"
"Wait.ani"
"Precision Select.cur"
"Text Select.cur"
"Handwriting.cur"
"Unavailable.ani"
"Vertical Resize.ani"
"Horizontal Resize.ani"
"Diagonal Resize 1.ani"
"Diagonal Resize 2.ani"
"Move.ani"
"Alternate Select.cur"
"Link Select.cur"

[Strings]
CUR_DIR         = "Cursors\pkuwyc\GANT_Blue_Colorful_24x24"
SCHEME_NAME     = "Gant Blue"
pointer     = "Normal Select.cur"
help        = "Help Select.ani"
work        = "Work in Background.ani"
busy        = "Wait.ani"
cross       = "Precision Select.cur"
text        = "Text Select.cur"
hand        = "Handwriting.cur"
unavailiable    = "Unavailable.ani"
vert        = "Vertical Resize.ani"
horz        = "Horizontal Resize.ani"
dgn1        = "Diagonal Resize 1.ani"
dgn2        = "Diagonal Resize 2.ani"
move        = "Move.ani"
alternate   = "Alternate Select.cur"
link        = "Link Select.cur"
```

I don't understand too much of driver installers, but as it is a .inf file it should work like a driver installer right? Or could it be that Windows does some special stuff again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Code did successfully install the Cursor:

```cs
public void InstallCursor(string installerFilePath)
{
    string command = @"C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe";
    string arguments = "setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 " + installerFilePath;

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = $"/c \"{command} {arguments}\"",
        Verb = "runas",
        UseShellExecute = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };

    Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = startInfo
    };

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Note that either the cmd you open or your Application that opens it, need to be run with Administrator priveleges to install the .inf file